# Compiling boost libraries

Tags: boost

Windows XP
Visual Studio 2008

I have downloaded and unzipped the boost_1.33.1. We have to use this version as our client application uses this version.

However, I want to compile the source file to create the libraries. However, when I read the documentation I says you have to execute the bootstrap and then Bjam. However, in the root directory of boost. There are no such files. Only boost-build.jam.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the bootstrapping thing is relatively new. You'll just need to download bjam.exe separately from [the boost website](http://www.boost.org/) (it's in the "Boost Jam" section).

Comment: Hello, I download loaded boost-jam-3.1.17. However, I get the following errors

C:\boost-jam-3.1.17\boost-jam-3.1.17>.\bootstrap\jam0 -f build.jam --toolset=vc9 "--toolset-root=c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\
Tools\..\..\VC\ " clean
Access is denied.

C:\boost-jam-3.1.17\boost-jam-3.1.17>.\bootstrap\jam0 -f build.jam --toolset=vc9 "--toolset-root=c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\
Tools\..\..\VC\ "
Access is denied.

Comment: You don't need to build bjam, I've always just used the pre-built binary for that. The error your getting seems to be related to the fact that you've unzipped the files as a different user to the one you're running bjam as.

Comment: Solved - need to set the compiler to VS 2005

Answer (score 2):

**My old notes on building boost on windows.**

build bjam:

```
cd C:\source\boost\boost_1_35_0\tools\jam\src
.\build.bat
```

If you need static libraries use: `--build-type=complete`

build libs (only `threads` in this case):

```
C:\source\boost\boost_1_35_0>tools\jam\src\bin.ntx86\bjam.exe
--build-dir=C:\source\boost\build
--toolset=msvc
--build-type=stage
--with-thread
```

Comment: Hello, I did try that by going to this directory. C:\boost_1_33_1\tools\build\jam_src. However, I got the same error as I posted in the comment Codeka. I opened up the visual studio command line, went to that directory and just typed> build

Comment: Solved - Needed to set the compiler to vs 2005